# Use Cats Effect Ref as a cache

Tags: scala, functional-programming, cats-effect

Trying to implement caching the functional way using Cats Effect Ref monad.

**Why is the internal Ref not be set as expected?**

```
import cats.effect.kernel.Ref
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}

object SomeMain extends IOApp.Simple {

  val cache: IO[Ref[IO, Option[String]]] = Ref.of[IO, Option[String]](None)

  override def run: IO[Unit] = {

    val checkValueBeforeSet = cache.flatMap(ref => ref.get.flatMap {
      case Some(v) => IO(println(v))
      case None => IO(println("as expected no value yet"))
    })

    val doSetAction = cache.flatMap(ref => ref.set(Some("abc"))).map(_ => println("set action done"))

    val checkValueAfterSet = cache.flatMap(ref => ref.get.flatMap {
      case Some(v) => IO(println(v))
      case None => IO(println("unexpected still no value set!"))
    })

    for {
      _ <- checkValueBeforeSet
      _ <- doSetAction
      _ <- checkValueAfterSet
    } yield IO()
  }
}
```

Output:

```
as expected no value yet
set action done
unexpected still no value set!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't work because you are creating `Ref` anew each time.

This:

```
val cache: IO[Ref[IO, Option[String]]] = Ref.of[IO, Option[String]](None)
```

is the same as:

```
val cache: () => AtomicReference[Option[String]] =
  () => new AtomicReference(None)
```

(If you don't understand the semantics of the `IO[A]` you can always imagine it is `() => A` or `() => Future[A]` and then it makes sense).

You are using `cache` twice (thrice) inside some helper method and these methods are creating local `Ref` and then let it be forgotten.

You'd have to keep the value returned by `cache` and pass it (w.g. with dependency injection) to make this work:

```
import cats.effect.kernel.Ref
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}

object SomeMain extends IOApp.Simple {

  val cache: IO[Ref[IO, Option[String]]] = Ref.of[IO, Option[String]](None)

  override def run: IO[Unit] = cache.flatMap { ref =>

    val checkValueBeforeSet = ref.get.flatMap {
      case Some(v) => IO(println(v))
      case None => IO(println("as expected no value yet"))
    }

    val doSetAction = ref.set(Some("abc"))).map(_ => println("set action done")

    val checkValueAfterSet = ref.get.flatMap {
      case Some(v) => IO(println(v))
      case None => IO(println("unexpected still no value set!"))
    }

    for {
      _ <- checkValueBeforeSet
      _ <- doSetAction
      _ <- checkValueAfterSet
    } yield IO()
  }
}
```

Basically, `Ref` is a wrapper around `AtomicReference` which runs each operation in an `IO`. It let mutate state safely but it's creation is unsafe on its own (`IO[Ref[]]` creates new `Ref` each time you compose it into the program), so you have to pay attention how you composing it into the program.

Alternatively, you can use `.memoize`, or create `Ref` with some `unsafe` method, but it's a great way of shooting yourself in a foot in a long run, if you don't have a very good intuition what you are doing.