# Use Cats Effect Ref as a cache - Part 2

Tags: scala, functional-programming, cats-effect

[Part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78130526/use-cats-effect-ref-as-a-cache)

The reason the value set in first-run isn't seen in the second-run and hence getting the message "strange! no value found in secondRun" is because every time I call:

```
cache.flatMap { ref
```

I'm getting a different 'ref' instance

**But why?**

**Is there way to fix/do this so that second-run would find the value set in first-run?**

```
import cats.effect.kernel.Ref
import cats.effect.{IO, IOApp}

object SomeMain2 extends IOApp.Simple {

  val cache: IO[Ref[IO, Option[String]]] = Ref.of[IO, Option[String]](None)

  override def run: IO[Unit] = {
    for {
      _ <- firstRun
      _ <- secondRun
    } yield IO()
  }

  private def firstRun: IO[Unit] = cache.flatMap { ref =>

    val checkValueBeforeSet = ref.get.flatMap {
      case Some(v) => IO(println(v))
      case None => IO(println("no value found in firstRun"))
    }

    val doSetAction = ref.set(Some("abc")).map(_ => println("set action done in firstRun"))

    val checkValueAfterSet = ref.get.flatMap {
      case Some(v) => IO(println(s"as expected value found: $v"))
      case None => IO(println("unexpected still no value set!"))
    }

    for {
      _ <- checkValueBeforeSet
      _ <- doSetAction
      _ <- checkValueAfterSet
      _ <- IO(println(s"ref: $ref"))
    } yield IO()
  }

  private def secondRun: IO[Unit] = cache.flatMap { ref =>

    val checkValue = ref.get.flatMap {
      case Some(v) => IO(println(v))
      case None => IO(println("strange! no value found in secondRun"))
    }

    for {
      _ <- checkValue
      _ <- IO(println(s"ref: $ref"))
    } yield IO()
  }
}
```

Output:

```
no value found in firstRun
set action done in firstRun
as expected value found: abc
ref: cats.effect.kernel.SyncRef@14dfe50a
strange! no value found in secondRun
ref: cats.effect.kernel.SyncRef@1bca3dbe
```

Comment: You need to understand that a `IO[A]` is a program that when evaluated will produce an `A`, always. I have some resources here that may help: https://github.com/BalmungSan/programs-as-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This is the same issue as in [part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78130526/use-cats-effect-ref-as-a-cache) but under a different form. The [answer from Mateusz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78130553/5389127) in the 1st question still applies here. Let me adapt it for you in this situation.*

You need to reuse the same `Ref` instance in all your program(s):

```scala
val cache: IO[Ref[IO, Option[String]]] = Ref.of[IO, Option[String]](None)

override def run: IO[Unit] = {
  for {
    cacheRef <- cache
    _ <- firstRun(cacheRef)
    _ <- secondRun(cacheRef)
  } yield IO()
}

private def firstRun(cacheRef: Ref[...]): IO[Unit] = {
  // do something with cacheRef
}

private def secondRun(cacheRef: Ref[...]): IO[Unit] = {
  // do something with cacheRef
}
```

---

Edit: this is a very basic approach though. In a real-life application, you would likely use dependency injection and hide the `Ref` instance in a shared service responsible to manage it. (Thanks Mateusz for pointing that out in the comments).